# Get random 8 images from directory for my game using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have developed a memory game from a set of images using `JS` and `PHP` and everything works fine. Now I'd like to expand this work and get images from the directory for the game.

**JS code** :

```
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var turnable = e.target.dataset.turnable;

        //first click
        if (!wait && lastKnownButtonId == undefined && lastKnownButtonNumber == undefined && turnable == 'true') {
            e.target.dataset.turnable = 'false';

            e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

            lastKnownButtonId = e.target.id;
            lastKnownButtonNumber = e.target.dataset.number;

        }
        //second click
        else if (!wait && lastKnownButtonId != undefined && lastKnownButtonNumber != undefined && turnable == 'true' && e.target.id != lastKnownButtonId) {
            e.target.dataset.turnable = 'false';

            e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);

            //match
            if (e.target.dataset.number == lastKnownButtonNumber) {
                e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#00FF7F';
                document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId).style.backgroundColor = '#00FF7F';

                lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
                lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;

                matches++;

                if (matches == 8) {
                    showWinScreen();
                    //clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
                    document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves;
                }
            }
            //no match
            else {
                document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                wait = true;

                setTimeout(() => {
                    e.target.dataset.turnable = 'true';
                    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(0);

                    var tempLastClickedButton = document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId);

                    tempLastClickedButton.dataset.turnable = 'true';
                    tempLastClickedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                    tempLastClickedButton.innerHTML = getgImage(0);

                    lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
                    lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;
                    wait = false;
                }, 1000);
            }
            moveCounter();
        }
    });
}

function getgImage(number) {
    switch (number) {
        case '1':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion1.jpg">';
        case '2':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion2.jpg">';
        case '3':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion3.jpg">';
        case '4':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion4.jpg">';
        case '5':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion5.jpg">';
        case '6':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion6.jpg">';
        case '7':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion7.jpg">';
        case '8':
            return '<img src="resources/fashion8.jpg">';
        default:
            return '<img src="resources/logo.png">';
     }
 }
```

So in the above code, I use a set of images in the switch case. Now **I'd like to use random 8 images from the directory called "resources"**. Is it possible to use `Jquery` to get random 8 images from the directory? I don't know how to proceed

Comment: jQuery can't do that, because browser can't do that without help of the backend. You'll need an endpoint that returns a random set of images, or the full list of images/files.

Comment: _“Is it possible to use Jquery to get random 8 images from the directory?”_ - only if you know their names upfront (resp. have a fixed scheme so you can “create” them dynamically); client-side JavaScript can not read the contents of any server-side directory by itself. If you don’t know the names upfront, then you would need to start with a PHP script that reads the directory contents, and passes the data on to your client-side script.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
arrayOfImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfImages.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, are they named like `fashion1`, `fashion2`, ..... `fashion8` if so you could just do this:

```
'<img src="resources/fashion' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1) + '.jpg">'
```

This would get you a random image. But if not, it's not possible until your client side code knows all the names upfront like in the comments